# Using Google's youtube API is there a way to determine if a video has been removed or no longer available?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, actionscript-2

I have been using the Google data API to search video from Youtube and play it back in a chromeless player as part of a Flash (AS2) swf I have developed. here's my workflow -

1. Search Youtube with PHP page that includes Zend_Gdata_YouTube class
2. Retrieve and display videos in a Flash swf which play if user clicks.
3. Store video ids in database for playback later - like a playlist
4. Then when the playlist is played (in another swf) the database is read to get the video ids to play and Flash loads the videos as needed.

Here's the problem. While the search works fine and returns thumbnail images of all the videos some of them do not play on click. Using Firebug in firefox I see that the attempted load of the video returns a 204 No content, but there is no info in the response tab. SO ...

- a) how would I catch these videos so they dont get returned in the search results?
- b) What would happen if a video that did play ok initially later got removed from Youtube, how could I catch this (preferably with flash) and remove it from the playlist (database).

any thoughts?
cheers